# repeatable marquee that's optional based on text width

Tags: javascript, css

I've spent most of my morning trying to resolve how to create a scrolling marquee on an Angular app; my goal is when the dynamic text is longer than its viewport, it will scroll (repeating, meaning you don't have to wait for the entire title to scroll off the page before you see it again) but when it's short enough to display without being cut off in the viewport width, it does not scroll.

I like examples I'm seeing but need to combine them somehow and I am very beginner when it comes to adding any kind of javascript.

One is using jQuery and marquee:

```
$('.marquee').marquee({
  duplicated: true
});
```

This one is great because it repeats the text and continues without it having to completely leave the screen to start again. But, my trouble comes when trying to figure out a way to add in javascript to figure out how wide that text will be; either to have it be static or scroll.

For some reason, I am unable to understand how to link to codepen or jsfiddle of the examples I've found that hit close to home. Hoping my inquiry above is enough information. I know commenters can be a bit rough—please be patient with me.

Comment: work out how to link your code or put it in a snippet, then ask the question.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @Timothy, I was just copying and pasting URLs for examples from the websites (both jsfiddle and codepen) and I've seen others post links to there as well (like below in a response) but I kept receiving an error, that I had to provide code along with it? I like the working example those sites provide and editable rather than embedding code. I don't wish to annoy people with my ignorance but I am open to learning how.

Comment: When posting on StackOverflow you must post code in your question at least the key part of it, but using snippets is best, then you will be allowed to link code.

Comment: Just think if all the linked died, would people still be able to understand your question and answer it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984613/how-do-i-include-code-for-jsfiddle

Comment: @Timothy appreciate the tips, quite a bit. I'm familiar with comments on Stack Overflow so thank you for your patience and help. I was a bit nervous posting, worried someone would say something not so nice :)

Comment: Thanks, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use text-shadow(to clone text) and animation if it is only about text.

JS will be necessary to get the width(from text lenght) of the piece to scroll and to update/insert css rule's values.

example inspired from your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppajer/zeuzzguk/1/)

```js
function isElementOverflowing(element) {
  var overflowX = element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth,
    overflowY = element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight;
  return (overflowX || overflowY);
}


// below css updated and injected . can be shorten and nicely rewritten
var element = document.getElementById('ov1');

if (isElementOverflowing(element)) {
  var toscroll = element.scrollWidth;
  element.style.textShadow = toscroll + 'px 0 ';
  element.style.animation = 'marqueeme 5s infinite linear';
  var csstyle = document.createElement('style');
  csstyle.innerText = '@keyframes marqueeme {100%{ text-indent:-' + toscroll + 'px;}}';
  element.appendChild(csstyle)
}
```

```css
#marquee {
  max-width: 15em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#ov1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="marquee">
  <p id="ov1">
    Yadda yadda overflowing text this line is too long oh noes!
  </p>
</div>
```

example here is using text-indent within the animation, but negative margin-left or translateX will do the same visual.

---

Another example with

- a text-shadow of different color
- transform to see it working instead text-indent.
- It also sets speed according to text length

@ https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/owPNZg

Comment: I was able to just look at this now—you are amazing! I truly appreciate your smarts and help. I'll be sure to pick around at it to learn how it all pulls together. Much appreciated.